# filter not being invoked by ArrayAdapter sub-class

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-filterable

It seems that this should be easy.

I have an Android app with a list using an ArrayAdapter. It works. I replace the ArrayAdapter with a custom sub-class. It works. I add a inner class that is a sub-class of Filter and mark the ArrayAdaptor sub-class as implementing Fiterable. And it works fine, except that it does not filter.

What is the magic word I have to say here?

None of the methods in the Filter sub-class are being invoked.

```
public class XYZListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<XYZListFragment.XYZItem> implements Filterable {

    private List<XYZListFragment.XYZItem> sourceObjects;
    private Context sourceContext;
    private XYZFilter xyzFilter;

    public XYZListAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<XYZListFragment.XYZItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        sourceObjects = new ArrayList<>(objects);
        sourceContext = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.i("XYZAdapter", "getView");

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            v = ((LayoutInflater)sourceContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.fragment_xyz_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        XYZListFragment.XYZItem mItem = sourceObjects.get(position);

        if (mItem != null) {
            TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.xyz_list_item_name_view);
            if (t != null) {
                t.setText(mItem.name());
            }
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Log.i("XYZAdapter", "getFilter");
        if (xyzFilter == null)
            xyzFilter = new XYZFilter();
        return xyzFilter;
    }

    private class XYZFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            Log.i("XYZFilter", "perform");

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                results.values = sourceObjects;
                results.count = sourceObjects.size();
            }
            else {

                List<XYZListFragment.XYZItem> nextXYZList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (XYZListFragment.XYZItem p : sourceObjects) {
                    if (p.name().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        nextXYZList.add(p);
                }

                results.values = nextXYZList;
                results.count = nextXYZList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            Log.i("XYZFilter", "publish");

            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                sourceObjects = (List<XYZListFragment.XYZItem>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am now using a SimpleCursorAdaptor. There were no answers here anyway, so ... la.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you shouldn't subclass the `ArrayAdapter` if you want to customize it's filtering logic.  You would need to implement an adapter from scratch using the `BaseAdapter`.

Basically, the `ArrayAdapter` internally tracks its own list of objects. However you are only updating your list of objects in the subclass.  You need to update the internal list as well.  Otherwise the adapter is not aware of the change.

There are other issues.  For instance, the `performFiltering()` method executes on a background thread. That means you need to synchronize any changes done to the list.  The `ArrayAdapter` already does this internally...and you have no way of accessing the sync lock object it uses...which makes it impossible for you to safely sync.

Also, your filtering solution doesn't seem to provide a solution for restoring the list back to its original state after the filtering is cleared out.

You can read more about the problems with `ArrayAdapter` filtering [here](http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/filtering-problems-arrayadapter/). General rule of thumb. When using the `ArrayAdapter` don't create your own list to track the data and don't customize the filtering. Optionally, you can use something like the [AbsArrayAdapter](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters) which is just like an `ArrayAdapter` but lets you define the filtering logic for you.